# Oracle SQL Developer vs Spring Query - sub select issue

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-jdbc

I have the following SQL query which runs correctly in Oracle SQL developer, but when it's executed via a standard java spring JDBCTemptate query it fails.

```
SELECT  
  REPLACE(:RUN_DATE,'-','/') as rep_day,
  9,
  'BILLING', 
  ROUND(x.duration_minutes),
  ROUND(x.duration_minutes),
  '(' || bc.description || ') ' || x.total_ba || ' Accounts; ' || (case when (x.duration_minutes/60) > 1 then FLOOR(x.duration_minutes/60)  ||'h'  end) || round(mod(x.duration_minutes,60)) || 'min'
FROM
  (SELECT bt.bill_cycle_id,
    bt.invoice_period,
    bt.invoice_period_end_date,
    sum((bt.execution_end - bt.execution_start)*24*60) AS duration_minutes,
    sum((
    CASE
      WHEN bt.task = 'BILL'
      THEN bt.number_of_accounts 
      else 0
    end))AS total_ba,
    min(trunc(bt.execution_start)) as start_date    
  FROM billing.billing_tasks bt
  WHERE bt.type                     = 'REAL_BILL_RUN'
  AND bt.status                     = 'COMP'
  AND trunc(bt.execution_start) = (SELECT to_date(MAX(START_DATE),'dd-mm-yyyy') FROM BILLING.BILL_RUNS WHERE TYPE='REAL_BILL_RUN')
  group by  bt.bill_cycle_id,
    bt.invoice_period,
    bt.invoice_period_end_date
  ) x
INNER JOIN billing.bill_cycles bc
ON bc.id = x.bill_cycle_id
```

The java code is

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Override
public List<KpiData> runQuery(String runDate) throws Exception {
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(oracleDataSource);
    Map map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(GenerateDailyReport.RUN_DATE, runDate);
    List<KpiData> kpis = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, map, new KpiDataRowMapper());
    return kpis;
}
```

I know the issue is with the 'trunc(bt.execution_start)' clause. The original date clause was this, where the :RUN_DATE was a parameter

```
AND trunc(bt.execution_start) = to_date(:RUN_DATE,'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

but i've updated the query to fetch the most recent bill run date.

```
AND trunc(bt.execution_start) = (SELECT to_date(MAX(START_DATE),'dd-mm-yyyy') FROM BILLING.BILL_RUNS WHERE TYPE='REAL_BILL_RUN')
```

Can anybody spot an issue with the SQL that causes this to fail?

Comment: How is it failing?  Please include the error message in the question.

Comment: No error per say - SQL developer return 1 row, the spring query returns zero rows.

Comment: If it is returning no rows, then it is probably a problem with the data.  You should add a SQL Fiddle to your question(s) to clarify what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In the sub-select rather than using 'to_date'

```
AND trunc(bt.execution_start) = (SELECT to_date(MAX(START_DATE),'dd-mm-yyyy') FROM BILLING.BILL_RUNS WHERE TYPE='REAL_BILL_RUN')
```

I just now call 'trunc()' to covert the existing Date type field START_DATE, to the same format as the left hand side operator 'trunc(bt.execution_start)'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you found a solution to your problem.

Interestingly though, your answer provided the missing clues as to why your original query didn't work, and I think it would be very useful to explain it.

What wasn't clear from your original post is that `start_date` is already a `date` field.  That being the case, it doesn't make sense to call `to_date()` on a `date` field.  `to_date()` should only be used to convert a string to a date, not a date to a date.

In fact, trying to invoke `to_date` on a date value very often leads to very unintuitive results, which is what you experienced.

Let's pretend for a second that `max(start_date)` is `Sept 21st, 2015`.  Then believe it or not, doing `to_date(max(start_date), 'dd-mm-yyyy')` will return you `Sept 21st, 0015` (not `2015`).  Try this query to confirm the odd behavior:

```
select to_char(to_date(max(start_date), 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  from BILLING.BILL_RUNS
 where TYPE='REAL_BILL_RUN'
```

What date do you get?  Not what you expected?

The reason why this happens is because `to_date()` expects a string parameter.  As such, when you pass it a date instead, it needs to implicitly convert your date to a string using the default date formatting before invoking `to_date()` function.  In other words:

```
to_date(max(start_date), 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

... really becomes this:

```
to_date(to_char(max(start_date)), 'dd-mm-yyyy') -- notice the to_char()
```

In the case of a date like `Sept 21, 2015`, the `to_char()` function probably returns you something like `21-SEP-15` (notice the 2-digit year).

And so, logically, trying to parse a string with a 2-digit year, while specifying the 4-digit year format, like this:

```
to_date('21-SEP-15', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

... will result in the year `0015` instead of `2015`. Not good.

In summary: ***never pass a date parameter to a call to `to_date()`***.